# Jquery Upload with Progressbar

Tags: ajax, upload, progress-bar

I have an Ajax-Upload script that works fine. Now I want add an progressbar or something else. How can I implement something like that in my script below:

```
  $('body').on('change', '#uploadFile', function() {

// Post-Data
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', this.files[0]);
data.append('uid', $("#uploadFile").attr('data-uid'));


// Ajax-Call
$.ajax({
    url: "uploadUserpic.php",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success : handleData 
});
});

function handleData(data) {
   $("#messagePic").html(data);

   //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with $.ajax, You need a XMLHttpRequest object.
Try this:

```
var data = [];

$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        // For Upload
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;

            }
        }, false);
        // For Download
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;

            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/echo/html",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GvdSy/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GvdSy/
doesn't seem to be working in Chrome version: 55.0.2883.75 m
but works fine in Chrome version: 46.0.2490.86 m
any ideas why?